# When I add links to images in display flex it breaks the layout

Tags: html, css

So I have some images laid with display: flex like this:

```
<img id = "vidmenu1" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/EmoSTXvo0NU/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
<img id = "vidmenu3" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/h0Nj8sVV7g0/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
<br style="clear:both" />                       
<img id = "vidmenu2" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/ohuuLmwER0A/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
<img id = "vidmenu4" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/mcWhnMmlNFE/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
```

Using the css code:

```
#parent_div {   display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-align:stretch;
display: flex; 
width: 100%;
flex-direction: row; 
flex-wrap: wrap; 
justify-content:space-around; 
width: 70%; 
border: 0; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0 }
#vidmenu1 {display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-align:stretch;
display: flex;  height: 50%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
#vidmenu2 {display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-align:stretch;
display: flex;  height: 50%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
#vidmenu3 {display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-align:stretch;
display: flex;  height: 50%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
#vidmenu4 {display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-align:stretch;
display: flex;  height: 50%; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0}
```

and it displays exactly like I want, which is in a two-by-two square. But when I add links to the images, like this:

```
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu1" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/EmoSTXvo0NU/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
</a>
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu3" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/h0Nj8sVV7g0/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
</a>
<br style="clear:both" />                       
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu2" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/ohuuLmwER0A/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
</a>
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu4" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/mcWhnMmlNFE/0.jpg" width = "50%" />
</a>
```

Then the display: flex breaks and the images are displayed one on top of the other block-style.

Why does adding links break the layout, and how do I get it to display with the links the same as it does without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some tweak in your html markup and style sheet to get your desired output but there are still many ways to achieve this

### UPDATE

I implemented it on your website and this was the result

[image: MODIFICATION]

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#parent_div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 650px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumb {
  height: 250px;
  width: 280px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #CACACA;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -moz-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-inline-flex;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div id="parent_div">
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu1" class="thumb" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/EmoSTXvo0NU/0.jpg"/>
</a>
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu3" class="thumb" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/h0Nj8sVV7g0/0.jpg"/>
</a>
<br style="clear:both" />                       
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu2" class="thumb" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/ohuuLmwER0A/0.jpg"/>
</a>
<a target = "vid_menu" href = "//www.youtube.com/embed/ohuuLmwER0A?list=PLAg45-Ox3WR4gODmcAmIYHVvCpngXcCTZ&amp;index=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0">
    <img id = "vidmenu4" class="thumb" src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/mcWhnMmlNFE/0.jpg"/>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an improvement.

Comment: Dont forget to vote up and select it as answer if it helps or wait for others to participate.

Comment: I don't have the rep now to upvote. I'm trying to answer some questions so I can.

Comment: Just below the vote sign, You will find a tick sign such as in this link [IMAGE](http://pasteboard.co/ZNmuQBX.png), It will be green once you click on it.

Comment: Okay, got it. Still fairly new to SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` tags most likely have their own set of styling properties assigned to them and cause the images "to break." Look at the styles for your links or post more code / link to page.

Comment: here is the css for my `a` tag:

    `a { border: 0px; padding:0px; margin: 0px}`

Comment: here's a link to the page as it is now: [link](http://mrstewartslessons.com/LangSite_150206/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that a big part of the reason it wasn't working was that I was using percentage widths in the html for the images, as in `<img src = ... width = "50%">` which is a no-no in HTML5. That wasn't the only problem, but a big part of it.